# Custom Blazor Select-component option-element @onclick not firing - How do I get it to fire?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, html-select, blazor-component

I am creating a custom Blazor component, and I need the select component to update the bound field with the selected value, this part is working. I also need it to execute a method passed in from the parent component, this part is not working.

I am able to pass the method into the custom component (child), but the `onclick` event of the option element of the select element is not firing.

I was able to implement this in a multiple select element, but it is not working in a select element.

How do I get this to fire and still update the bound data property?

`ESelect.razor` Custom (child) select component

```
@inherits InputBase<string>

<div class="form-floating">
        <select class="form-control form-select @CssClass" id="@Id" @bind="@CurrentValue" >
            <option disabled selected></option>
            @foreach(SelectOption option in Options)
            {
                <option id=@option.Id onclick="@( () => OnClick(option) )" >@option.Value</option>
            }
        </select>
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Label))
        {
            <label class="form-control-label" for="@Id">@Label</label>        
        }
        <div class="form-control-validation">
            <ValidationMessage For="@ValidationFor" />
        </div>
</div>
```

`ESelect.razor.cs`  (C# code for ESelect.razor)

```
using BebComponents.DataModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace BebComponents
{
    public partial class ESelect
    {
        [Parameter, EditorRequired]
        public Expression<Func<string>> ValidationFor { get; set; } = default!;
        [Parameter]
        public string? Id { get; set; } = "ESelect";
        [Parameter]
        public string? Label { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public List<SelectOption> Options { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public SelectOption? SelectedOption { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public Action? Trigger { get; set; }

        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
        {            
            result = value; 
            validationErrorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }

        public void OnClick(SelectOption option)
        {
            SelectedOption = option;            
            Trigger?.Invoke();
        }

    }
}
```

`SelectOption.cs` (datamodel)

```
namespace BebComponents.DataModels
{
    public class SelectOption
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Index.razor`

```
@page "/"
@using BebComponents
@using BebComponents.DataModels
@using static BebComponents.EDualSelect

<EditForm Model="Form" OnValidSubmit="ValidFormSubmit" class="mt-5">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <h3>Form Example:</h3>
    <ValidationSummary />
    <h3 class="mt-4">Enhanced Select</h3>
    <ESelect Id="ESelect" @ref="eSelect" @bind-Value="Form.LastName" Options="@options" ValidationFor="@( () => Form.LastName )" 
        Label="Last Name" Trigger="EnableEnhancedSelect2"/>
    <h5 class="mt-2">The last name selected is:</h5>
    <p>@Form.LastName</p>
</EditForm>
```

`Index.razor.cs`

```
using BlazorComponents.Pages.PageModels;
using BebComponents;
using static BebComponents.EDualSelect;
using static BebComponents.ESingleSelect;
using static BebComponents.ESelect;
using BebComponents.DataModels;

namespace BlazorComponents.Pages
{    
    public partial class Index
    {
        private ESelect eSelect;
        private string eSelectResult;
        private readonly List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>
        {            
            new SelectOption { Id = 1, Value = "Jones" },
            new SelectOption { Id = 2, Value = "Smith" },
            new SelectOption { Id = 3, Value = "Bender" },
            new SelectOption { Id = 4, Value = "Baggio" },
            new SelectOption { Id = 5, Value = "Allen" },
            new SelectOption { Id = 6, Value = "Biggs" },
            new SelectOption { Id = 7, Value = "Randall" },
            new SelectOption { Id = 8, Value = "Anderson" },
            new SelectOption { Id = 8, Value = "Reeves" }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want to run some code when any item is chosen or when a particular item is chosen? You've put your onclick on an item y'see..

Comment: *How do I get this to fire?* - I think I'd trigger it off the changing of the property that the select is bound to instead, if some value X is being set, do something

Comment: I'd recommend Instead of using onclick per option, try use onchange at the select level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Simple Solution**

Your existing code can be made to work with one minor addition.

You can see a working example in this [Blazor Fiddle Demo](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/jja9tw4d) Blazor Fiddle is rather limited, but I've tried to keep the code close to the original.

Your click handler never fires because an `<option>` element only fires when the parent is a `<select multiple>`. Yet, in this case it's just a default single `<select>`and will never fire. We might use the onchange event instead, which is usually how this is done. Yet, we could also just add a wrapper around the CurrentValue property, which would allow you to reuse the code you already have.

CurrentValue is a property inherited from InputBase. And to invoke the parent supplied Trigger method you will need to wrap CurrentValue to provide that new functionality. This can be done by using the ["new" keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) and calling the method in the setter as shown.

Code to add to the component:

```
[Parameter]
public new string CurrentValue 
{
    get => base.CurrentValue;
    set {
        base.CurrentValue = value;
        Trigger?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

*You may also want to remove the existing onclick handler from the markup since it doesn't do anything and would only be misleading.*

Comment: Agreed that this works.  It "hides" the base property.  But why set it as a public parameter?  Why not create a new private field, say `_currentValue` with the same pattern as yours and then bind the `Select` to it - `@bind="@_currentValue"`.  I'm not a great believer in "Hiding".

Comment: @Tyson - does this answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

#### Updated Answer:

Here's a revised answer that shows you how to build out a composite control - in this case a select - and link in the binding.  I've simplified the options setup.

I've added an extra `ValueHasChanged` `EventCallback` that gets triggered whenever the value is changed.  I use it to print a time update to show it working.

```
@typeparam TValue
@using System.Linq.Expressions

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        @this.Label
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <InputSelect TValue=TValue Value=@this.Value ValueChanged=this.OnValueChanged ValueExpression=this.ValueExpression>
            @ChildContent
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <ValidationMessage For=this.ValidationFor />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Label { get; set; } = "Field Label";

    [Parameter] public TValue? Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<TValue>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Expression<Func<TValue>> ValidationFor { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue> ValueHasChanged { get; set; }

    private void OnValueChanged(TValue value)
    {
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        if (this.ValueHasChanged.HasDelegate)
            this.ValueHasChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

And a test page:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
<EditForm Model=model>
    <MySelect Label="Country" TValue=int @bind-Value=model.Value ValueHasChanged=this.OnValueChanged ValidationFor="() => model.Value" >
        <option value=1>Spain</option>
        <option value=2>Portugal</option>
        <option value=3>France</option>
    </MySelect>
</EditForm>

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    Value = @model.Value
</div>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
    Value = @message
</div>

@code {
    private MyModel model = new();
    private string message = string.Empty;

    private void OnValueChanged(int value)
        =>  this.message = $"Updated at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";

    public class MyModel 
    {
        public int Value { get; set; } = 3;
    }
}
```

#### Original Answer:

Your code is bit complex to decipher.  Here's a simple example to demonstrate how to use a select and capture the change event on it.

The important bits to understand are:

1. You can't bind to an `Option.`
2. Binding with `@bind` uses the `Onchanged` event on the select so you can't also bind to it.  Instead use `@oninput` to bind to an event handler.
3. The value returned is a string, so you need to do some parsing to get it to say an int.
4. If you're triggering an event you need to check that the value has actually changed and only call the Event Callback if it has.

```
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<select @bind=this.Value @oninput=OnChange>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div>
    value: @this.Value
</div>

<div>
    Int Value: @this.IntValue
</div>

@code {
    public EventCallback<int> OnValueChanged;

    private string Value = "3";

    private int IntValue;

    private async Task OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = e.Value;
        if (int.TryParse(e.Value?.ToString(), out int value))
        {
            if (value != IntValue)
            {
            this.IntValue = value;
            if (this.OnValueChanged.HasDelegate)
                await this.OnValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like what you have done it is a good solution. Four our purposes, using the @oninput would cause the event to fire after ever character was entered. This would not be effective for what we need.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide some more code that may help .  It shows how to build out a composite control using `InputSelect` and how to wire it up to both bind correctly and drive a separate OnChange callback you can use.

Comment: I again like what you have done, but we are creating custom elements that inherit from InputBase so that we can have flexible CSS formatting on our webform controls when necessary. We cannot use InputSelect.

Comment: I'm up voting your solution because using onchange and typeparam are very good improvements and probably more standard.  Yet, I still like my answer better, though I am a little biased  ;)